# Free software to convert PDF to HTML

Tags: pdf, html, file-converter

I want to convert PDF to HTML and I don't want to get hard and long HTML code. I want to get easy to understand and short HTML code. But I don't know how. I need a free software.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements. Especially missing: on what OS must it run, what features must it support (eg. tables and multi-column texts are often issues with such converters). Also, what do you mean by long/short HTML code?

Comment: Extracting the text is hard enough, let along converting to simple HTML. Read the Blogpost [What's so hard about PDF text extraction?](https://filingdb.com/b/pdf-text-extraction) Conclusion:  "If the data you are interested in only comes in the PDF format, then it’s important to be aware that this is a deceptively simple-looking problem and that a 100% accurate solution may very well be impossible."

Comment: Note that this question was asked already, with several answers [here](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/19081/70045). However, it was in 2015, I don't know if the answers are still up-to-date.